# Using EMULATED_STORAGE_SOURCE & EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET env variables in Android application

Tags: java, android

I am developing an Android app in KitKat which locates a file (from Java layer) & open, read and process the contents of it from native layer. As part of this, the Java layer gets the path of the file (for ex: /storage/emulated/10/DCIM/foo.txt) using "Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()" and pass the path to our native layer via JNI. The native layer tries to open the file using the absolute path received from Java layer(which is /storage/emulated.../foo.txt). The problem is that, there is no such folder (/storage/emulated/**10**) exist in the native's file system.

I understand Android follows the FUSE filesystem in Java layer and so the actual file (foo.txt) is residing in the path: /mnt/shell/emulated/10/DCIM/foo.txt with respect to the native layer's filesystem.
So for my current requirement, From Java layer I need to pass the path which is meaningful in native layer. I could see that Android uses the environment variables EMULATED_STORAGE_SOURCE (pointing to /storage/emulated) & EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET (pointing to /mnt/shell/emulated) internally for mapping the files between Java layer & native layer. Currently I have used these environment variables in my Java application to convert the file's path from FUSE filesystem to native layer's filesystem.

My question is, is it safe to use the environment variables EMULATED_STORAGE_SOURCE & EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET in my Android application to manipulate the file path corresponding to native layer. If not, is there any alternate methodology to retrieve the actual path of file in native file system from Java application.